# How to (conditionally) remove SCRIPT_NAME from MEDIA_URL in urls.py

Tags: django

Situation: working in Debug=True mode in Django. I want to serve files from the media root, so I follow [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) hint:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And it works perfectly (remember to read the note: MEDIA_URL should be local i.e. `media/`. Don't put a `/` in front of it. Important!). I have a media resource called `123456.txt`, in the admin interface I get the link: `/media/123456.txt`.

Now I move to Apache (still in debug), but I run this Django site in a subfolder of the server, and everything works fine, thanks to the WSGI variable SCRIPT_NAME which gets prepended to all URIs. So just to be clear, I have `https://example.com/subfolder` as the root for the Django site and the previous media resource called `123456.txt`, in the admin interface I get the link: `/subfolder/media/123456.txt`. So the link is correct.

When I request the resource `https://example.com/subfolder/media/123456.txt`, Apache recognizes the subfolder and sends to Django a request for `media/123456.txt`, as expected.

The problem is that the url pattern created by the `static()` helper function now includes the SCRIPT_NAME prefix, so when I click on the resource, I get an exception (Page not found 404) where it says that the request doesn't match the pattern `^subfolder/media/(?P<path>.*)$`.

In the final deployment, this will not be a real issue, because either Apache will be serving the files, or I'll have a view for `media/` in order to control accesses, but it still bugs me.

Do you have any suggestion to solve this, or is this simply the intended behavior and I have to cope with that?